# Ad Hoc Deployment Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

When using ad hoc deployment in accelerator I get all green checks and no errors. However when you install the .ipa file it never compeletes. It gets about 80% done and then fails.

If you deploy locally to a devices it works. (hooking up to the computer & using itunes). all emulators work great.

I have tested on several devices and the same issue occurs on all of them. I have tried to create a new project and recreate files in the resource folder.

Any ideas on what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To make ad-hoc deployments work with TestFlight (which sounds like the analogous problem you have), I did roughly:

- right click on the app root in the Titanium Studio and choose Publish -> Configurations
- find the config labeled "Titanium Apple Ad Hoc/Enterprise Distribution"
- click the small new button at the top left of the list and give it a name
- fill in the "steps" on the right, in particular the Distribution Cert & Provisioning Profile

After doing this, you can build by selecting this config. I have found if you add a new device via iTunes, you need to download the profile (of course) and then go back into this dialog and select the Provisioning Profile again, but I'm not quite sure if that's necessary.